# pandas extracting column names with values greater than a threshold in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
             A         B        C       D ........
   AB        2         1        3       4 ........
   BC        1         3        5       4 ........
   CD        3         2        6       3 ........
   DE        2         1        2       2 ........
```

I want to extract all the column names where the value is greater than 2 for a specified row  and I want these column names returned in a list. So for example if I want this for row "AB", then the result should be like

```
  ['C', 'D', (all further column names with value greater than 2)]
```

and if I want this for row "BC", then the result should be like

```
  ['B', 'C', 'D', (all further column names with value greater than 2)]
```

I tried for over an hour looking online for something that can help me with this, but couldn't find anything. Could someone please help me with this? I will very much appreciate any help

Comment: What is your input and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select row by index value and filter columns names by condition for greater like `2` by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
out = df.columns[df.loc['AB'].gt(2)].tolist()
print (out)
['C', 'D']
```

If need processing all rows use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
out1 = df.gt(2).apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1)
print (out1)
AB       [C, D]
BC    [B, C, D]
CD    [A, C, D]
DE           []
dtype: object
```

Comment: out1 = df.gt(2).apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1) is giving empty lists for all rows

Comment: @user18334254 - there are numeric values? Maybe need `df.astype(int).gt(2)`

Comment: this gives the same row name as all items in the list

Comment: @user18334254 - what is `print (df.dtypes)`

Comment: all columns show float64

Comment: @user18334254 - hmm, so all columnsnames are shown? Is possible all data are greater like `2` ?